# How to separate h2 tag in array and value in another pos of array

Tags: php, html

Hi there i'm having problem to create an array in which the h2 will get in separte array pos and other below value in another position of array

```
<h2>While registration its showing email address already exists</h2>
<p>You can use one email address</p>
<h2>While registration its showing </h2>
<p>The usernames are unique.</p>




        [{
        'ques' = "How do I register?",
        'ans' = "You can register in MachPrinciple.com"
        },
        {
        'ques' = "While registration its showing email address already exists",
        'ans' = "You can use one email address for creating a single profile. You can log in to your profile using the email address",
        },
        {
        'ques' = "While registration its showing",
        'ans' = "The usernames are unique. So if someone has already taken a username then you can't register using the same username"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you please add proper input and expected output  ?

Comment: Mam it is proper above you are seeing a h2 tag so, need that whole in array[0] pos and below any value will be in another pos

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting !!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for.

```
 $input = [ 
            "<h2>hi</h2>",
            "<p>there</p>",
            "<p>there</p>",
            "<h2>hwo ar eyou</h2>",
            "<p>Im' not bdoy</p>",
            "<h2>is is good ? </h2>",
            "<p>Not it is not</p>",
        ];
        $outputArray = [];
        $i= -1;
        foreach($input as $in){
            if (str_contains($in,'<h2>')){
                $i++;
            }
            $outputArray[$i][] = $in;
            
        }
```

This will be the output

```
[
  [
   "<h2>hi</h2>",
   "<p>there</p>",
   "<p>there</p>"
  ],
  [
    "<h2>hwo ar eyou</h2>",
    "<p>Im' not bdoy</p>"
  ],
  [
    "<h2>is is good ? </h2>",
    "<p>Not it is not</p>"
  ]
]
```